# VBA: Pivot filter based on value range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new with VBA and I would like to have a code to select a pivot filter based on a cell range.
How can I change "CurrentPage" to be a range value ?

```
  Sub PrintTour()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Bereich 1].[Tour].[Tour ]"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Bereich 1].[Tour].[Tour]"). _
        CurrentPage = "[Bereich 1].[Tour lt. Anlieferungstag].&[4001-01]"
  End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: lookup `worksheets().range().value`. Why not just use slicers? I suggest because if you continue down this route you'll need to put this in an onchange event to have it automatically refresh.